# Get all referees referred from usernames with same IP. Members can have more than one account

Tags: php, mysql

I want affiliates to be able to see how many referrers they have.

So my table has 3 columns: `id`, `IP`, `username` and `referee`. A member can have more than 1 account.

Here is what I have so far.

```
//Get all of that IP's usernames
$sql = "SELECT username FROM ".MYSQLTABLE." WHERE ip = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

//Select all usernames, who's referee = one of IP's usernames (using above query) 
$sql1 = "SELECT usernames FROM ".MYSQLTABLE." WHERE referee = '".$res."'";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1)or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res1))
{
```

Comment: Your query doesn't look too bad, what isn't working?

Comment: stop using mysql_* commands, they are deprecated.

Comment: Not sure why it didnt work but they guys solution beneath worked a charm! Cheers Jim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this is a single query which will simplify things:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.username)
FROM yourTable u
INNER JOIN yourTable r ON (r.username = u.referee AND r.ip = 'TheIP');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Working perfectly :) Well it worked Strawberry.